# Value of objects stored as array

Tags: sql, json, postgresql-9.5

```
Select p."objectId" as "ObjectId-Key" 
      ,d."key" as "Key"
      ,(select "label" from "Field" f where f."objectId" = d.key) as "Label"
      ,d.value
      ,(select "value" from "FieldOption" fo where fo."objectId" = d.value) as "Field_Value"
from "Product" p  
  join jsonb_each_text(p."metadata") d on TRUE
Where 
--P."productType"= 'wne'
--and 
p."reference" = 'SFX001N0112'
```

I am trying to get the value of d.value from "FieldOption" which sometimes is an object Key or an array of object keys.

I managed to get the values when it is one key and it returns null when it is an array.

can someone advise how to extract the value of the object if it is an array.
Thank you!

sample of my output is 
[image]

In line 11, "value" is an objectid, which is stored as an array. I need to extract the value of the object.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. We also need to know the data types of the columns you are talking about. [Formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557).

Comment: What is the exact data type of the column `value` -  `text[]` or `text`  or something else? The output seems to indicate that it's a `text` column not [an "array"](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/arrays.html)

Comment: Are you sure you can use d.value as an Id in the FieldOption where clause? Values like 2012, Lola and South Australia looks very different from the other rows in that column. maybe what you have in the value column for some rows actually belongs in the Field_Value column?

Comment: p."metadata" is a jsonb object storing the keys and values. Some of the values are straightforward  where as some of the values are objects (row 10) or array of objects (row 11). so is why i am taking each value out and joining with "FieldValue" table to get the exact value.

Comment: @ a_horse_with_no_name "value" looks like a text as i am using jsonb_each_text